# Hidden control at Coded UI

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to record coded UI for a WPF application. My goal ls to click on button (`Mybutton`).

The problem is that in the application there is another control which in not visible and it lays on top of my button. Each time i'm clicking `myButton` - the code which the CUIT generates is for the blockingControl.

I have the app code - but have no permissions to change the xaml (I can add my own implementation such "onCrerationAutomationPeer").

Is there a way to write a plug in which will know to recognize that the BlockingCcontrol is not visible - and will not choose it?

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of Mouse.Click(BlockingControl.Rectangle.X,BlockingControl.Rectangle.Y)? This would send a mouse click to the top left corner of the blocking control. I am assuming they overlay pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that if I implement `onCrerationAutomationPeer` to return null
the blocking control will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you can also ask if the button is enabled.

```
if(button.GetProperty("Enabled").Equals(true)) { ... }
```